# Read-only file system problem in several systems

Tags: read-only

I was experiencing this problem with ubuntu 12.10, i changed to ubuntu 15.04 and still have the same problem. i formatted the whole Hard drive with NTFS and FTA32, reinstalled ubuntu 15.04 and tested it for 15 minutes. the problem showed up again, i can't sudo, i can't use apt and firefox shuts down.
I reformatted the hard drive and installed xubuntu 14, after almost 10 minutes the same problem showed off!
am not that expert in linux systems and i tried to get your help here before but no one wanted to help.
i really need a permanent solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same problem earlier this year.  I would zip files on my NTFS partition and they would be 600 privileges when I unzipped them on the web server.  I couldn't change the privileges either.

It turns out that NTFS (and in your case, FAT32) is the problem.  Ubuntu automatically translates all files in either format as 600 (owner read/write only.)

I fixed it by creating an ext4 partition and copying the files there.  Then I changed all the privileges of folders to 744 and files to 644 so I could use them on the website.

Comment: I tried both NTFS Andd FAT32 , umm i tried to change privileges using console in recovery mode and live cd  but that didn't help

Comment: you'll need to use the ext file format to get unix privileges